# Is there a way to validate, from the DBMS side, if a "boolean" column is already checked (true) in the table but for a subset of rows only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using MSSQL Server and I want to know if there is a way, from the DBMS side, to validate if a "boolean" column is already checked (true) in the table but for a subset of rows only.

Here's an example:

I have the following tables

**Users**

```
id | name
--------------------
10 | John Smith
11 | Lee Sin
```

**Types**

```
id | name
--------------------
20 | Developer
21 | Tester
22 | User
```

**UsersTypes**

```
UserId  | TypeId | IsDefaultChoice
--------------------
10      | 20     | true
10      | 21     | false
11      | 20     | true
```

I want to insert into a table "UsersTypes" the following:

```
UserId  | TypeId | IsDefaultChoice
--------------------
10      | 22     | true
```

* Note: There will be multiple rows with "true" value in the "IsDefaultChoice" column across the table, but I want that only one row may be set to "true" per group of UserId in the table "UsersTypes".

**I'm looking for a way to force the insert to fail because the user "John Smith" has already one entry "IsDefaultChoice" to true and can't have two "true" entries for this user upon insertion (or update)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_usertypes_default
    on usertypes(userId)
    where IsDefaultChoice = 'TRUE';
```

This will ensure that `IsDefaultChoice` is set for at most one row in `UserTypes`.  Note that this potentially complicates updating rows to a new default -- you have to be sure you unset the previous one.

Note that SQL Server does not have a `boolean` type.  I assume you mean `bit`, which does recognize `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'` as valid values.

Comment: Yes, I meant "bit" type.